# Is the linear function in a linear regression model an estimator for the population mean?

Tags: regression

My professor mentioned this offhand, but I don't understand what he means. Given a linear model $Y=β_0 + \sum_{j=1}^pX_jβ_j + ε$, in what sense is $f(X)=β_0 + \sum_{j=1}^pX_jβ_j$ an unbiased estimator of the population mean of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

In the subgroup of potentially observable $Y$ data where $ X$ is fixed at the value $x$, the mean is called $E(Y | X= x)$   (some would call this the "population mean", but that is a silly designation, because there may be little or no data in the finite population for which $X = x$.)

If the collection of such means satisfies  $E(Y | X= x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$, for all possible $x$, then, assuming finite expectations, $E( \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$. This can be proven using the algebra of expectation.

Short answer: Yes, if the model is correctly specified, then the predicted mean $( \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 x$) is unbiased.

However, since linearity is always false in reality (except in the case where $Y$ and $X$ are independent, and in the case where $X$ is binary), the predicted mean is almost always a biased estimate in reality.